# postcode checker for UK

Tags: addressbook, postal-code

I want to use an postcode checker. Here I will put post an postcode in textbox. then it automatically filter all UK addresses related to that postcode. From where will I get this api? Is it payable or free? And also provide how to use this api. Please give me the details information of this api. I am working in php.

May I need to buy this api? From where will I buy this api? Please help me ...

Thanks,
Ripa Saha

Comment: Maybe a good question for the UK postal service or a similar organisation?

Comment: UK or otherwise, Why do you want  all addresess for a post code? That seems like a huge amount of data to deal with.

Comment: Have a look at [AFD](http://www.afd.co.uk/). We use their product [Postcode Plus](http://www.afd.co.uk/product_postcodeplus.asp) to perform a similar task within our product

Comment: @ryadavilli My project have this type of requirement.

Comment: @DMK are there any demo site for AFD. May I check "AL5 4BT" this postcode filtering result?

Comment: There are evaluation executables for each of their products. The standard postcode lookup demo can be found [here](http://www.afd.co.uk/startdownload.asp?file=ftp://ftp.afd.co.uk/Postcode/pceval.EXE). They also have a demo [API](http://www.afd.co.uk/commonapi/index.asp?expand=Guides&sec=downloads) which you can make calls to. Both have either a limited data set or time out after so many days, can't remember which.

Answer (score 2):

Royal Mail also offer this service , their data set is likely to be the most comprehensive and upto date as new postcodes/streetmappings are changed.

See the PAF file (Postcode Address File)

http://www.royalmail.com/marketing-services/address-management-unit/address-data-products/postcode-address-file-paf?campaignid=paf_redirect